# Create Array of Arrays with different sizes in scala

Tags: arrays, scala

I would like to create an Array of Arrays like Array[Array[Double]] this,such that the outer array is of a different length say 11 and each elements of this array is another array of another size say 100.
So in short create an array which has 11 arrays as elements in it ,which in turn has 100 entries in it using Scala

Comment: How do I specify a size of 100 for all the the 11 arrays?

Comment: Seems we are having problem with understading your question. Is structure you are trying to obtain equivalent to two dimensional array of 100x11? If yes please read post that  @Yuval linked.

Comment: Thankyou @Yuval for pointing me to the correct post .

Comment: Thankyou @Marcin for confirming the same.